# How to uninstall adroid-sdk from Ubuntu

Tags: android-sdk

to install the android sdk on linux I typed:

```
$ sudo snap install androidsdk
```

which should have been:

```
$ sudo snap install android-sdk
```

Now I cant remove it with:

```
$ sudo snap remove android-sdk
```

Does anyone know what to do? Is there a possibility that it is a virus?

Comment: It is named [`androidsdk`](https://snapcraft.io/androidsdk) . So you have to remove it with `snap remove androidsdk`

Comment: `android-sdk` and `androidsdk` are very different package names for a computer; just as you need to be precise to get a package installed; you need to be equally accurate in removing the package. Your own question highlights your issue (you used a different package name to install it than what you tried to remove)

Comment: I am trying to remove android-sdk, not androidsdk, and it says that it doesnt exist

Comment: Use `snap list` to view what snaps you have installed.  You can only remove the snaps you actually installed.

Answer (score 0):

There is no android-sdk snap package so you couldn't have installed it as running the `snap list` command will verify.

The androidsdk snap package contains android sdkmanager and android SDK console tools. To uninstall the Android SDK snap open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap remove androidsdk
```

For reference purposes this is how you might have installed the latest version of Android SDK in Android Studio.

1. Select *Tools* -> *SDK Manager*.
2. In the *SDK Platforms* tab, select *Android 12*.
3. In the *SDK Tools* tab, select *Android SDK Build-Tools 31*.
4. Click *OK* to install the SDK.